# How to disable a connection using nmcli over ssh on a virtualbox machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, networkmanager, nmcli

I can disable a connection using the command below on a virtual machine (CentOS 8):

```
nmcli con down connection_name
```

But, when I'm using SSH to manage the VM OS, the command above, does not do anything and the console does not response to ctrl+c/ctrl+d and gets freezed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe sounds like you disabling the connection over which you are connected via ssh into the VM.
Obviously, when this connection goes down, then there is no more reaction on your console and it looks like the console is froozen.
If I'm right, then you can end the 'dead' ssh client on your side with the key sequence <kbd>Return</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but I have to add some more details, when I am connected via SSH to my own local system (Xubuntu), the command works!

Answer (score 0):

Use one-liner:
`nmcli conn down eth0 ; nmcli conn up eth0`
This will work even without breaking existing SSH connection.